# $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $\{a - \frac1n|n\in \mathbb N^*\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I have looked at similar questions on here but still cannot reach a conclusion for this particular one.
I have gathered that as n increases, $\frac1n$ tends to $0$, meaning $a - \frac1n$ tends to $a$.
So the set must be bounded below by $a - 1$, and bounded above by $a$.

To prove $\inf(A) = a - 1$, I started by assuming that $\inf(A) = l$ for some $l > a - 1$.
So $a - l < 1$.
Set $a - 1 = ε$.
By Archimedean Property, there exists some $ñ > ε$.
So $ñ > \frac1{\epsilon} \implies a - l > \frac1ñ$

This seems to imply $l < a - \frac1ñ$, so I did not arrive at a contradiction. Does this mean there is another possible value for the infimum? I can't think of what it could be.

Comment: Please use MathJax to formulate questions.

Comment: Note that $a-1$ is the minimum of your set and therefore the infimum.

Comment: Just note that $1 = \frac 11$ so $a-1 \in A$.

Comment: Does this mean that a rigorous proof by contradiction is not required and simply stating this fact is enough?

Comment: @i.diazr You can rigorously show that the minimum and infimum of a set are equal if they both exist. You should try this yourself!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do things in order. First, manipulating inequalities to highlight a minorant and a majorant; and then prove that it's the $\inf$ and the $\sup$.
$$\text{let }1\leq n$$

> $$0< \frac1n \leq 1$$$$-1\leq -\frac1n<0$$

$$\color{red}a-1\leq \color{red}a-\frac1{\color{green}n}<\color{red}a$$
Then, as @hff1 and @fleablood said, $a-1=a-\frac1{\color{green}1}$ is the $\inf.$

What you still have to prove is that $$\forall \epsilon>0, a-\epsilon  \text{ is not a majorant}$$to prove that $a$ is the smallest of the majorants, i.e. the $\sup.$

And the arguments you have cited are used as follows :

> $$\text{Let }\epsilon >0$$$$\text{Let }\widetilde{n}>0 \text{ s.t. } \widetilde{n}\epsilon>1$$$$\epsilon>\frac1{\widetilde{n}}$$ $$-\epsilon<-\frac1{\widetilde{n}}$$$$\color{red}a-\epsilon<\color{red}a-\frac1{\widetilde{n}}$$